# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous .. Yii2

Tags: yii2

Here i ran into this below error while am trying to search in Yii2 gridview

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `leagues` LEFT JOIN `country` ON 
`leagues`.`country_id` = `country`.`id` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Eredivisie%'
```

the below sql code was generated by Yii, so i don't know how to the causes of the sql error or how to manipulate it. Below is my search model that shows the relations between the two table

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\League;


class LeagueSearch extends League
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
        public function rules()


  {
        return [
           [['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
           [['name','country_id'], 'safe'],
       ];
    }

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = League::find();


    $query->joinWith('country');
    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['name' => SORT_ASC]],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country.name',$this->country_id]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

name is a column in league table, country is also having a column called name so i think sql is missing up something here. Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: use table name with the column , as there is `name` column in country table too

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam yes you're right, but i'm using Yii2 so i didn't write a raw sql, and i don't know how to achive this using Yii2  `$query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'country.name',$this->country_id]);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have the `name` column in both tables, `country` and `league` that is why you are getting the error.

> Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous

Change the following line

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
```

to

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', '{{%league}}.name', $this->name])
```

OR

**Assign an alias to the `league` table**

```
$query = League::find()->alias('l');
```

and use that alias for the `name` column in the `league` table like below

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'l.name', $this->name])
```

---

Another thing is that you are comparing the `country_id` with country `name` column?

```
andFilterWhere(['like', 'country.name',$this->country_id]);
```

you should compare with the `country.id` instead if the `$this->country_id` has an id inside it.

Comment: a big thanks to you, using alias on the table solved the problem